# msysgit bash shell thinks argument is a UNC path when it's not

Tags: windows, git-bash, msys

I'm trying to call TFSBuild from the Git Bash shell but I'm not having any luck.

Using

```
"$TFSBUILD" start //Collection:http://tfsserver
```

converts the second argument to

```
//Collection:http://tfsserver
```

so the argument will not work because it has two slashes at the start.

Using

```
"$TFSBUILD" start /Collection:http://tfsserver
```

converts the second argument to

```
/Collection:http:/tfsserver
```

so the command will not work because a slash has been removed from the URL.

It looks like for the first option, [MSYS Bash thinks the path is a UNC path, so it's not removing the first slash](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion):

> An argument starting with 2 or more / is considered an escaped Windows
>   style switch and will be passed with the leading / removed and all \
>   changed to /. Except that if there is a / following the leading block
>   of /, the argument is considered to be a UNC path and the leading / is
>   not removed.

Is there any workaround or any way to turn off this behavior? I've tried all sorts of combinations of quotes, running on cmd /c instead, using variables, and nothing has worked yet.

Comment: MSYS is not MinGW. And technically, you can't be sure MSYS is the same as the MSYSgit shell, or the [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/) shell. Have you tried the latter? It is more up to date with respect to the Cygwin base, and the packages it comes with.

Comment: I'm making a tool for my whole team and I need this to work in the standard Git Bash shell.

Comment: I'm not sure what's standard about msysGit's bash shell, FWIW, it's based on a really old and buggy fork of Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the solution in PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 2):

On MSYS2 you can do:

`export MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="//Collection"
"$TFSBUILD" start //Collection:http://tfsserver`

.. MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL is a semi-colon separated env. var that MSYS2 compares each part of with the front of each argument. If there's a match then that argument is not converted. msysGit doesn't have this feature/pragmatic hack.